# Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. Yet I clearly have to host there

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I have a site written in PHP that I'm creating. But I'm having this issue when I connect it to the database. When I load the page, I get the top:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:     No such host is known. in C:\Program Files\Apache Software   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\socialtest\inc\connect.inc.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\Program Files\Apache   Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\socialtest\inc\connect.inc.php on line 7
```

This is connect.inc.php. The file which establishes the connect to the MySQL database:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('USER','PASSWORD','SERVER','DATABASE');
#OR die('Captian, we have failed' .
#     mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

The server name is 'localhost' and I never had a problem with it until recently.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue as I've tried everything I can think of and I'm out of options.

I'm using Apache2.2, PHP .5.6.9 and MySQL56 on Windows Vista.

Thanks!

Comment: The first parameter should be the server name.

Comment: When someone gets out of his mind , he will be modifying a different file and he is checking the deployed file for the changes he made on the server. Same error leads to this as well. So Keep follow the traces again.

Answer (score 5):

As "[mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario)" said, your mysqli_connect syntax is wrong.

http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.construct.php

The right syntax is for example :

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Comment: I did that and I'm not getting the error anymore! Thanks. But apparently I'm using the wrong password so I'll have to figure that out.